# how to write .htaccess mod rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using a .htaccess file and attempting to write three different rewrite rules.

I am trying to turn http://e-innovate.co.uk/webstats/s.php to http://e-innovate.co.uk/webstats/ so i am hiding the "s.php"

```
#RewriteRule ^http://e-innovate.co.uk/webstats/s.php$ http://www.e-innovate.co.uk/webstats/ [R,NC,L]
```

In the below two rules i am trying to change the local the script is searching for the image.

```
#RewriteRule ^/cPanel_magic_revision_1391334393/unprotected/cpanel/images/login-whisp.png$ http://www.e-innovate.co.uk/images/failed_authentication.png [R,NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^/cPanel_magic_revision_1391334231/unprotected/cpanel/images/cpanel-logo.png$ http://www.e-innovate.co.uk/images/failed_authentication.png [R,NC,L]
```

I have tried the above rules but they are not working and there is no error messages generated, it just appears the rules are being ignored, have i written these wrong as i know i am missing something but i am not sure what i am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below rule will help you with the first condition.

```
RewriteRule ^/webstats/?$ /webstats/s.php [L]
```

In case if you need redirection then add `R` flag to the rule. If you need more debugging information on mod_rewrite you can enable it with below directive (trying this directive in production will slow down your apache response).

```
LogLevel info rewrite:trace5
```

Regarding your second and third condition they look perfect and should work. What is the error you are getting ?